# How to get the first table where i know the id from second table

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

I need to get both table and here is the table structure

### Table A

- UserID
- Username
- Status
- IntroCode

### Table B

- IntroCode
- UserID

I want to get the table a data and join with table b on tblA.IntroCode = tblB.IntroCode, then get the username of tblB.userID. How can i do such join ?

I tried half way and stuck in the middle, please help. Thanks for reply

Comment: Thx for effort of you all guys, responces is super fast =) and the correct answer is answer from @John Woo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a simple join.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*    -- select your desired columns here
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
            ON a.IntroCode = b.IntroCode
WHERE   b.userid = valueHere
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.UserID, 
        a.`Username` OrigUserName,
        a.`Status`,
        c.`Username` IntroUserName
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
            ON a.IntroCode = b.IntroCode
        INNER JOIN tableA c
            ON b.userID = c.userID
-- WHERE b.UserID = valueHere       -- extra condition here
```

Comment: but there're 2 username. how can i do it ? one is the original data username and the other one is intro's username

Comment: +1 for speed and accuracy - also a great opportunity to link @SLim to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables which was written to further explain this sort of question and answer :)

Comment: @SLim what do you mean by two username? anyway i just updated the answer. Maybe `where` clause can help you.

Comment: Refer to them using the table prefix. Use any of the queries provided, and replace **B.userId** with **B.userId as userId**

Comment: I don't understand and i guess you misunderstand? What i mean is i want to get the username of the row, and also i want to get the username or introguy.

Comment: @SLim maybe I get your point, you need to add another join to get the username of the ID. i will update my answer.

Comment: Exactly!! I need to get Username of TableA also i want to get Username owned by UserID in TableB

Comment: @Slim did you check my answer... replied with the answer before

Comment: @JohnWoo, Yea !!! I Got It !!!!, Mr. Bokw, Sorry.. i go through one by one and he is the first person gave the answer =( and i don't have the ID so i need to get all..

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.UserID=TableB.UserID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT B.userID from TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.IntroCode=B.IntroCode
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*,b.IntroCode  from TableA a left join TableB b
on a.IntroCode = b.IntroCode
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to give the columns with same name an unique value:

```
SELECT  a.UserID as uid_a, b.UserID as uid_b
FROM    tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.IntroCode = b.IntroCode
WHERE   b.UserID = 1
```

Comment: the OP don't need the `UserID` but the `Username` for each ID.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query.

```
 SELECT TableA.Username FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON (TableA.IntroCode = TableB.IntroCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this query

```
SELECT  *  FROM tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.IntroCode = tblB.IntroCode where tblB.userid = value
```